# PySimpleGUI: How does one bind an element in a tab environment?

Tags: pysimplegui

I have a cashbook program that makes use of TABS to separate receipt entries from expense entries. In both the 'Receipts' and 'Expenses' tabs there is an Input element for entering a money value. I want to bind the element so that when losing focus it converts the figure entered to a format with 2 decimal places. (see:event=='-RECAMNT-FOCUS OUT':). The problem is that when I run the code an error comes up stating that you cannot perform operations on an element until read() is called or finalize=True when window is created.
The binding works perfectly in a program with just a main window (without tabs). Can anyone please tell me how to solve this problem? I am unable to add 'finalize=True' where the window creation has 3 layouts.
window =sg.Window('Cash Book',layout).Layout(tabgrp).layout(layout3)

I am posting extracted code to show where the problem appears to arise.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
import sqlite3
import datetime as dt
import time

sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('GreenTan')#LightGrey

menu_def = [['File', ['Open', 'Save', 'Exit'  ]],      
           ['Edit', ['Add a Patient','Add a Supplier']],
           ['Reports',['Fuel uplifts by registration','Fuel uplift by Town']],     
           ['Help', 'About...'], ] 

conn=sqlite3.connect(r'/home/bushbug/Databases/FSCashBook')
cur=conn.cursor()
query=cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(pName)from Patients Order by pName ASC")
patient_data=[]

for row in cur.fetchall():
    patient_data.append(row[0])
    cur.close()

conn=sqlite3.connect(r'/home/bushbug/Databases/FSCashBook')
cur=conn.cursor()
query=cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(sName)from Suppliers Order by sName ASC")
supp_data=[]

for row in cur.fetchall():
    supp_data.append(row[0])
    cur.close()

conn= sqlite3.connect(r'/home/bushbug/Databases/FSCashBook')
cur=conn.cursor()
query=cur.execute("SELECT IncCat from Analyse where Indicator = 'I' ")
I_Analyse_data=[]

for row in cur.fetchall():
    I_Analyse_data.append(row[0])
    #return data
    cur.close()

conn= sqlite3.connect(r'/home/bushbug/Databases/FSCashBook')
cur=conn.cursor()
query=cur.execute("SELECT IncCat from Analyse where Indicator = 'E' ")
E_Analyse_data=[]

for row in cur.fetchall():
    E_Analyse_data.append(row[0])
    #return data
    cur.close()

conn= sqlite3.connect(r'/home/bushbug/Databases/FSCashBook')
cur=conn.cursor()
query=("SELECT fBal from FSCashBook ORDER by Id DESC LIMIT 1")
result=cur.execute(query)

for row in result:
    Balance=row[0]

conn= sqlite3.connect(r'/home/bushbug/Databases/FSCashBook')
cur=conn.cursor()
query=("SELECT tDate from FSCashBook WHERE tInd = 'I' ORDER by Id DESC LIMIT 1 ")
result=cur.execute(query)

for row in result:
    LastDate=row[0]
    
layout1=[
[sg.T('Last transaction date',key='-RECTRANSDT-'),sg.In(LastDate,key='-IN4-', size=(10,1)),sg.T('Patient name:'),sg.Combo(patient_data,size=(15,1),key='-PATIENT-'),sg.Push(),sg.T('Amount'),sg.In(size=15,key='-RECAMNT-')],
[sg.T('')],
[sg.T('Document No:         '),sg.In(size=8,key='-RECDOC-'),sg.T(''),sg.T('Procedure'),sg.In(size=20,key='-PROC-'),sg.Push(),sg.T('Analysis:'),sg.Combo(I_Analyse_data,size=20,key='-RECANALYSE-')],
[sg.T('')],
[sg.CalendarButton('Choose receipt date',button_color='blue', target='-IN4-', format='%Y-%m-%d'),sg.Push(),sg.Button('Next Receipt',button_color='purple'),sg.Button('SaveRec',button_color='green')]]

layout2=[
[sg.T('Last transaction date'),sg.In(key='-IN5-', size=(10,1)),sg.T('Supplier name:'),sg.Combo(supp_data,size=20,key='-SUPPLIER-'),sg.Push(),sg.T('Amount'),sg.In(size=15,key='-EXPAMNT-')],
[sg.T('')],
[sg.T('Document No:         '),sg.In(size=8,key='-EXPDOC-'),sg.T(''),sg.T('Transaction details'),sg.In(size=20,key='-TRANSDET-'),sg.Push(),sg.T('Analysis:'),sg.Combo(E_Analyse_data,size=20,key='-EXPANALYSE-')],
[sg.T('')],
[sg.CalendarButton('Choose expense date',button_color='blue',  target='-IN5-', format='%Y-%m-%d'),sg.Push(),sg.Button('Next Expense',button_color='purple'),sg.Button('SaveExp',button_color='green')]]

tabgrp=[[sg.TabGroup([[sg.Tab('Receipts',layout1,key='-RECEIPTS-'),#,title_color='Green',border_width=10,background_color='White',tooltip='Enter receipts',element_justification='centre'),
sg.Tab('Expenses',layout2,key='-EXPENSES-')]], tab_location='topleft',
                       title_color='Red', tab_background_color='Purple',selected_title_color='Green',
                       selected_background_color='Gray', border_width=5), sg.Button('Close')]] 
layout3=[
[sg.T('Closing balance: '), sg.In(size=10,key='_CLOSBAL_')]]

layout=[
[sg.Menu(menu_def, )], 
[sg.Push(),sg.T('FootSmart Cash Book',font=('Verdana',24,'bold'),text_color='turquoise'),sg.Push()],
[sg.Push(),sg.T('Enter transaction details in one of the TABS below',font=('Verdana',18,'bold'),text_color ='turquoise'),sg.Push()],
[sg.T('')],
[sg.T('')],
[sg.T('')],
[sg.T('Opening balance: '), sg.In(Balance,size=10,key='_OPBAL_')]
]

window =sg.Window('Cash Book',layout).Layout(tabgrp).layout(layout3)

window['-RECAMNT-'].bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')   

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel','Close'):
        break

    elif event=='-RECAMNT-FOCUS OUT':
        try:
            frecamnt = (values['-RECAMNT-'])
            frecamnt = "{: .2f}".format(float(frecamnt))
            window.find_element('-RECAMNT-').update(frecamnt)
            print(frecamnt)
            #continue
window.close()
```

Comment: Can't say I've ever seen 3 layouts separated like that before.  Combine them into 1 layout (as Jason has also shown) and you'll be able use the `finalize` parameter:   `window = sg.Window('Cash Book', layout+tabgrp+layout3, finalize=True)`

Comment: Thank you Mike. I did just what Jason said and it works perfectly. I have posted two further questions and look forward to seeing what the solutions are.

Comment: Post them on the GitHub please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Many of the Window methods require you to either call Window.read or Window.Finalize (or set finalize=True in your Window call) before you call the method. This is because these 2 calls are what actually creates the window using the underlying GUI Framework. Prior to one of those calls, the methods are likely to crash as they will not yet have their underlying widgets created.

My suggestion

```py
window =sg.Window('Cash Book',layout).Layout(tabgrp).layout(layout3)

window['-RECAMNT-'].bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')
```

should be replaced by

```py
layout += tabgrp + layout3
window = sg.Window('Cash Book', layout, finalize=True)
window['-RECAMNT-'].bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')
```